# Информация не пригодит(ь)ся?

Tags: орфография, глаголы

Как правильно будет: "*Информация не пригодит(ь)ся"?*

Answer (score 2):

В таких случаях написание глагола с мягким или без мягкого знака проверяется вопросом: информация что (не) сделае**т**? — Информация (не) пригоди**т**ся.
Мягкого знака в данном случае нет в глаголе *сделает*, — не нужен он и в глаголе *пригодится*. Для сравнения, во фразе *информация может пригодит**ь**ся в будущем* мягкий знак в глаголе нужен. (Проверочный вопрос: информация что может сделат**ь**? — Информация может пригодит**ь**ся в будущем.)